# How to migrate data from SqLite to Firebase realtime database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my first version of android app I have used SQLite database. Now I want to convert everything to Firebase real time database. I don't want to use SQLite database anymore because of offline capabilities of firebase. Since previous version of app has a number of user and everyone has their own data stored, I don't want, user lose data while upgrading app. How I migrate previous version SQLite database to new version Firebase real time database? TIA

Comment: I'm looking for a solution too, I think that querying everything and doing push test with the firebase structure would be the best option.

Comment: You don't. Well, you don't directly migrate as SQLite is SQL and Firebase is NoSQL; there are significant differences between them in how data is structured and queries are performed. FB has no tables, no inner joins and no AND, IN, or OR queries. However, if the data is structured correctly, all of those functions can be done. Start with gaining a clear understanding of [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), and then craft some code to massage data from your SQL tables into parent: child (key: value) structures for Firebase.

Comment: @Matteo Unfortunately you cannot just query everything and push it to Firebase as the data won't be in a usable (JSON) format and more importantly, that data will need to be restructured based on what you want to get out of Firebase. Duplicating data, denormalization and compound values are very common in Firebase and not-so-common with SQL.